# how to calculate rx, ro given gx and go from XSPICE

Tags: transistors, bjt, spice, multisim, transconductance

I have a set of XSPICE data extracted from multisim as can be seen in the attached image. How do I calculate the ro and rx (base spreading resistance) given the parameters go and gx.

Thanks
[image: XSPICE Parameters of BJT]

Comment: Don't you just do the reciprocal of G to get R?